# Can't find spreadsheets v3 API in Google Developers Console

Tags: java, gdata, google-sheets-api

Which is the right API for manipulating Spreadsheets?

They somehow removed Spreadsheets v3 from the api selection in the project settings.Yet it's available at the OAuth Playground...

Is it just the Drive API v2 now?

Why do they have to change everything so fast and leave no documentation at all...

Even their gdata-samples.java-1.47.1 are outdated since most still use OAuth 1.0
*The GData Java Doc ist really horrible and their examples are so pointlessly bloated*

Comment: Suggest you re-write this. I understand you have hit problems, you are not the only one. by re-writing you may help someone in the same boat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Manipulate spreadsheets

Use the  Spreadsheets v3 (Gdata) API
If I remember, you just need OAuth2 setting up. Or an API password is an easy way to test things, as the OAuth2 setup is a pain.

### Google-apps-script

There is also 'Google-apps-script', it can edit spreadsheets and much more. It is High level compared to GData and has far more features and can do many things that Gdata can't but gdata has better fine grain control.

### Drive API

Drive API is good if you want to download the whole spreadsheet as PDF/CSV or something. But not for making changes to cells.

### Ethercalc

There is also ethercalc, open source, so gives you much more control.

Answer (score 4):

Although Sheets API does not appear in the list of API Libray, you can create an Oauth2 client or Public API access to use it. Sheets API is accessible by default, and we do not have to explicitly enable it.

OAuth 2.0 allows users to share specific data with you (for example, contact lists) while keeping their usernames, passwords, and other information private.